# C++ Upper Triangular Matrix Bracket Operator

Tags: c++, matrix, operator-keyword, square-bracket

I've hit a road block with a certain project of mine. I want to create an Upper Triangle Matrix (all elements below the diagonal are zero) that allocates only the memory necessary to hold the nonzero elements. The problem that I'm having is indexing into this matrix. I would rather not have to redesign the matrix, but if that is the only solution, then I can accept it. As a side note, the Vector is my own implementation, not the stl Vector.

So far I have the class declared as follows:

```
template <class T>
class UMatrix : public AbstractMatrix<T>
{
  private:
    Vector<T>* m_data;
    int m_size;
  public:
    //lots of member functions
};
```

The constructor of the Upper Triangle Matrix:

```
template <class T>
UMatrix<T>(const int size)
{
  m_size = size;

  if(size < 1)
    throw(RangeErr(size));

  m_data = new Vector<T> [size];
  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    Vector<T> init(i + 1);
    m_data[i] = init;
  }
}
```

And the code that I'm having trouble with:

```
template <class T>
Vector<T>& operator[] (const int index)
{
  if(m_data != NULL && index >= 0 && index < m_rows)
  {
    // Insert dark magic here
  }
  else
  {
    throw(RangeErr(index));
  }
}
```

This results in an array of staggered vectors, each vector being 1 length larger than the previous.

I am attempting to implement the bracket operator such that `UMatrix[a][b]` accesses row a, column b of the true Upper Triangular Matrix. This means that `UMatrix[a][b] == 0` when `a > b`.

The bracket operator is also a virtual function from the abstract base class, and must return a Vector&. Also, this implementation must use the bracket operator, not the function () operator, so that it is compatible with previously written code. I am aware that it would be simpler to use a dense matrix, but I am limited to only necessary memory usage.

My first attempt involved using one vector for storage, similar to a 1d array matrix. However, the bracket operator is also seemingly impossible to write for that implementation as well.

My question: is it even possible to implement this bracket operator?

Comment: `new Vector` is usually wrong. Why not just have a vector object? To make 2d `[]` operator you have to use a proxy object. It's easier to add `operator()` which takes any number of parameters.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The professor changed the project specifications to allow for the parenthesis operator overload. This is the best method available to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know if this is accepted solution since you have not provided anything about `Vector` class. You can create another class let's call it `SparseVector<U>`, where you will have the code like this

```
virtual U& operator[](int i) {
    if(m_data != nullptr) {
        if(m_nnzb <= i && i <= m_nnze) {
            return m_data[i - m_nnzb];
        }
    }
    throw std::runtime_error("bad index: in SparseVector::operator[]");
}
```

Here the idea of this implementation. This is a vector of size `m_size` where we store only non-zero elements in range from `m_nnzb` to `m_nnze`. And we use this class for subscript operator in matrix class. Here is the full code with small example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <stdexcept>

/* vector interface */
template<typename T>
class IVector {
public:
    virtual T& operator[](int i) = 0;
};

/* matrix interface */
template<typename T>
class IMatrix {
public:
    virtual IVector<T>& operator[](int i) = 0;
};

/* implementation for upper triangular matrix */
template<typename T>
class UpperMatrix : public IMatrix<T> {
public:
    /* implementation for sparse vector */
    template<typename U>
    class SparseVector : public IVector<U> {
    public:
        SparseVector() {
            m_size = m_nnzb = m_nnze = 0;
            m_data = nullptr;
        }
        SparseVector(int size, int b, int e) {
            m_size = size;
            m_nnzb = b;
            m_nnze = e;
            m_data = new U[e - b];
        }
        SparseVector(const SparseVector<U>& other) {
            m_size = other.m_size;
            m_nnzb = other.m_nnzb;
            m_nnze = other.m_nnze;
            m_data = new U[m_nnze - m_nnzb];
            for(int i = 0; i < m_nnze - m_nnzb; ++i) {
                m_data[i] = other.m_data[i];
            }
        }
        virtual U& operator[](int i) {
            if(m_data != nullptr) {
                if(m_nnzb <= i && i <= m_nnze) {
                    return m_data[i - m_nnzb];
                }
            }
            throw std::runtime_error("bad index: in SparseVector::operator[]");
        }
    protected:
        int m_size;
        int m_nnzb;
        int m_nnze;
        U*  m_data;
    };
    UpperMatrix(int n) {
        m_size = n;
        m_data = new SparseVector<T>[n];
        for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            m_data[i] = SparseVector<T>(n, i, n);
        }
    }
    virtual IVector<T>& operator[](int i) {
        if(i < m_size && m_data != nullptr) {
            return m_data[i];
        }
        throw std::runtime_error("bad index in UpperMatrix::operator[]");
    }
protected:
    int              m_size;
    SparseVector<T>* m_data;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    UpperMatrix<int> m1(3);
    /* correct index */
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        for(int j = i; j < 3; ++j) {
            m1[i][j] = i + j;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        for(int j = i; j < 3; ++j) {
            std::cout << m1[i][j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    /* incorrect index */
    try {
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
                m1[i][j] = i + j;
            }
        }
    } catch(const std::exception& ex) {
        std::cout << "error occured: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is even in the name: I should not be using memory to store anything other than nonzero values. However, I think I've solved my problem by using a reverse vector class that inherits from a Vector. The only difference is that the bracket operator returns `m_data[m_size - index]` instead of `m_data[index]`.

Comment: @DanielGrooms And just two integers is the problem?

Comment: Imagine this: `Matrix<int> large(10000);`. This is the problem with sparse memory storage.

Comment: @DanielGrooms 1) I don't need anything to imagine, but you need to calculate: let's say we have upper triangular matrix of size n = 1000, so there is 500000 non-zero values (1000*1000 / 2) and to store it we need additional 2000 integers. But they are take less than 1% of all storage (2000 / 502000 = 0.39%)! And you think this is a big deal? 2) Your question was "is it even possible to implement this bracket operator?". I provided one solution,  I have not say there are no others. I have shown you that you need to create another ``Vector`` class, that's the point, but you don't see it either.